# What approach to be used on application side in migrating web services to HTTPS from HTTP?

Tags: ios, web-services, http, https

i have an app running on Apple app store with webservices from **HTTP Server** but now i want to migrate my webservices from **HTTP Server** to newly brought **HTTPS Server**. What is the best approach to achieve this without affecting older application users running application on **HTTP Server**?

P.S: After migrating to new server, older server will not work.

Edit: my older server domain is going to expire and also i have amazon server on which i am going to move my webservices. So the older and new server link are different.

Thanks

Comment: the new server should support both HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: new server only support https @bayou.io